# Why this matrix is not diagonalizable?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let be $A$ a  $n\times n$ matrix such that, rank($A)=n-1$ and rank($A^2)=n-2$. ¿Why a matrix like that is not diagonalizable?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You may first consider how the ranks of $A$ and $A^2$ are related to each other when $A$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: If $B$ is the Jordan form of $A$, which is diagonal, then rank of $B$ is the same as rank of $A$, that is $n-1$, so the diagonal of $B$ has $1$ zero and $n-1$ non-zeroes. The same is true for $B^2$ and $rank(B^2)=n-1$. But $rank(B^2)=rank(A^2)=n-2$, a contradiction.

Comment: Can you find a matrix $A$ that meets the criteria?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $A$ is diagonalizable, it's not restrictive to assume that $A$ is diagonal. How many diagonal entries are equal to $0$?

What about $A^2$?